# Interfacing after installation of driver module?

Tags: raspberry-pi, driver, linux-device-driver

I installed this [module](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/477f70cd2a67904e04c2c2b9bd0fa2e95222f2f6/drivers/gpu/drm/tiny/ili9486.c) and have the corresponding `RaspberryPi HAT(Waveshare Rpi 35A)` attached to my Raspberry Pi.

After running `modprobe ili9486` in the terminal:
In `/sys/module`, I see the device.
In `/dev/` and `/dev/spi/`, I don't see anything with `ili9486` in it's name.

How do I send a command to the device?

In specific how do I send the command to `ili9486_probe`, which will in turn, send the command to `waveshare_command`? My goal is to get the command to reach `waveshare_command`?

I didn't install the `dtoverlay` on the [Waveshare github](https://github.com/waveshare/LCD-show/blob/master/LCD35-show) because I do not want touch screen features. I just want to write to the screen.

Comment: You need to use corresponding kernel interface. Seems either framebuffer (/dev/fbX) or DRM (/dev/driX),